# Xcopy is missing parameters and will not copy files

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I am trying to make a .bat file that will copy another batch file to the windows start up directory. but XCOPY keeps saying it is missing parameters, can you have a look at my code and see where I'm going wrong.

```
xcopy "c:\Desktop\CHAOSCOPY.bat" *.* "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp\"

xcopy "c:\Desktop\CHAOS V2.bat" *.* "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp\" 

xcopy "c:\Desktop\CHAOS.bat" *.* "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp\"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xcopy` syntax is

`xcopy sourcedecription destinationdescription`

(disregarding any switches)

What is your code supposed to do? Is `"c:\Desktop\CHAOSCOPY.bat"` a file you want to copy? If so, copy it to where? What has `*.*` got to do with the matter? It specifies `all files with an extension`. Do you want to copy `all files with an extension` from the current directory and also `"c:\Desktop\CHAOSCOPY.bat"` to the destination? If so, you need two separate `xcopy` commands. `cmd` cannot read your mind - it can't tell which of the three parameters is source and which destination.

Comment: I want to transfer those 3 Files to the destination folder so.

"CHAOSCOPY.bat" I want to be copied to C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp\

"CHAOS V2.bat" and "CHAOS.bat" I also want copied to that location

Comment: I'm not that good with batch files.. but all I need is those files copied to the destination.. ignore the whole file extension thing that's a mistake

Comment: Omit the `\*.*`

Comment: I removed the `*.*` and it started working. Thanks for your help :)